# Render inside turbo_stream template tag

Tags: hotwire-rails

Why rendering partial inside `<template>` tags of stream.erb file raises `ActionView::MissingTemplate` error?

For example in some_action_in_controller.turbo_stream.erb file i have;

```html
<turbo-stream action="some_action" target="some_target">
  <template>
    <div class="some-class">
      <% @some_records.each do |r|
       <%= render partial: 'some_partial', locals: { data_to_partial } %>
      <% end% >
    </div>
  </template>
</turbo-stream>
```

In this case i use `<turbo-stream>` tag instead of <%= turbo_stream.. %> since in my stream file, i render more than just a partial to maintain the UI in page where i am streaming the data.

Why am i getting the error? and what is actually happening?

Comment: For anyone who is stuck on this, a way to achieve this was to simply append `format: [:html]` parameter inside the render tag. Eg, `<%= render partial: 'some_partial', locals: { data_to_partial }, format: [:html] %>` And there you go, you get the partial working inside stream. Hope it helps! :))))

Answer (score 3):

Add `formats: [:html]` to the render statement.  Note that this is **formats** plural, unlike the previous answers.

```rb
<%= render partial: 'some_partial', formats: [:html], locals: { data_to_partial } %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also change your partial's format, rename from:

`some_partial.html.erb` to  `some_partial.turbo_stream.erb`.

Specifying the `format: [:html]` on render didn't work for me on `rails 7.0.2.4`, `turbo-rails 1.0.1`.